Should a researcher be included as author if they contributed significantly to a project?
I have a question about authorship. I am coming from a humanistic field (music) in which researchers don't usually have research teams, so probably team-based publication practices have not entered the culture yet.
There is a PI that is responsible for a project. The PI had two assistants (a doctoral candidate and a postdoc) that were working on the project for about 25 hours a week and created the design, and contributed to the collection and creation of data upon which future publications that are part of the project will be made (e.g. public report of the results of the project published in a journal).
The PI suddenly starts to write independent papers with only the PI's name, and does not report the assistants in the authorship (basically, does not ask them to contribute to the writing up or revision of the text), but just mentions some contribution of the assistants in a footnote.
Is the approach correct?
In the case, one of the two assistants was the person that independently wrote the whole proposal to get the funding for the research, therefore also designing the idea and overall methodology, should the PI mention that?

Has the data been published before by the team, and are they cited in the "independent papers" of the PI? How independent are these papers, do they still operate within the framework of the project or do they build on it and extend the results, so that they contain conclusions based on results the PI found without the others?

Hi @Snijderfrey, they are within the framework of the project. About the data been published: there are 2 papers that were submitted when data was not available. The data was made publicly available just some weeks ago, and I was just informed that they are finalizing a new article right now. Also about containing the conclusions: well, I was not part of the process of interpreting data, nor asked to participate.

Unfortunately, the norms of what is needed for authorship vary a lot from field to field. In math and most STEM fields at least, this would likely be enough that they should have authorship. But for example in law, that would not be the case.

If the data is now publically available in an initial paper with everyone's name, writing a separate paper without the original people, if the first paper does have their names on it, would probably be ok in most fields.

Hi @JoshuaZ, I definitely agree that people can make their own papers with the available data. However, I suppose that you mean that the author should clarify whether the paper is considered or not as within the framework of the project? What's your view about that?

@TakeMeToTheMoon Without more info that's very hard to say. And even with more info, this may vary a lot from area to area. There is not one single norm about how this works.

Thank you @JoshuaZ, I don't completely understand. Even though things may change from field to field, some general guidelines should still be valid (for example: it depends on how the process of collecting/creating data was tied to the publication). Otherwise, is it there really accepted that multiple people work on a project, and one team member uses that work to publish alone? (I would say that it is possible if the topic of the publication is not directly related to the project's scope). I will leave the post open if somebody wants to give some additional perspectives.

@TakeMeToTheMoon The range varies. In physics, it often takes little to be an author; doing a routine calculation or taking measurements using an instrument may suffice. In law, even massive amounts of work may not if one is a paid R.A. Math is often in between, with bio being more generous than math but in some respects less so than physics. If one is in a field where there's no norm, then there's little to say. Some people have tried to make some larger guidelines, such as with COPE, https://publicationethics.org/authorship but that's only a starting point, and doesn't apply to all fields.

Ok, many thanks!

The literal answer to your question is "not necessarily". Or, perhaps, "it depends". Separate the idea of the "project" from that of the "papers". They aren't the same. More is required for authorship than contribution to the project. It isn't the time and effort on the project that requires authorship, but the formation and expression of the ideas in the specific paper that does.
What is required, and it seems to be present here, is acknowledgement of contributions.
There are also "field norms" that contribute to decisions about authorship. High Energy Physics (as done at CERN, for example) seems to be generous with authorship. In other fields "gift authorship" is strongly discouraged.
I can't, however, make any judgement about your case without knowing a lot more. In math, for example, someone can earn authorship in a five minute conversation with someone if they produce the crux of an important proof. "Did you think about trying....?" might be enough. But that is because they provided the "big idea" that makes it work. The opposite can also be true.

Thank you Buffy, but would you not change eventually your sentence "More is required for authorship than contribution to the project" into "depends on the type of contribution and its role within the scope of the publication/project" (if it is not open data by someone else)? Let's suppose that, in biology, there is a student that is growing up a cell culture for 3 weeks, and another team member notices something particular that is worth publishing. How may people consider the work "behind" the discovery (let's remember that we are in a team project, not just separate individuals)?

Actually, that suggested change isn't what I mean. It is quite opposite to the meaning intended. Sorry.
